# Custom text with EmailJS

Tags: javascript, email

I'm trying to display a custom message for a boolean with emailJS (pure JS).

On my code below, `location1` is a checkbox. `NewYork` correctly write in the email *true* or *false*. But textNewYork return an empty string (even if the console return *yes* or *no* before *SUCCESS!*).

I tried a lot of configarations but nothing seems to work (and I'm new to JS so I'm quite limited...).

Any idea?

````js
function validate() {
  const varsForm = {
    NewYork: document.getElementById("location1").checked,
    textNewYork: "",
  };

  emailjs.send("service_ID", "template_ID", varsForm).then(
    function () {
      console.log("SUCCESS!");
    },
    function (error) {
      console.log("FAILED...", error);
    }
  );

  var textNewYork = "No";
  if (document.getElementById("location1").checked) {
    textNewYork = "Yes";
    console.log(textNewYork);
  }

}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. the reason for consoling yes before success is because the function `emailjs.send()` is asynchronous function.

so js Ignore the block code between `emailjs.send()`  and Start executing bellow lines and Waits for `emailjs.send()` to return any value then code Executes it corresponding block code.

```
const varsForm = {
  NewYork: document.getElementById("location1").checked,
  textNewYork: document.getElementById("location1").checked ? 'YES': 'NO',
};
```

Here it will check if its `true` then it will initial `YES` else `NO` to `textNewYork` property.

Comment: Ok, thanks for this explanation, it makes sense. But is there any way to make it works as I intend ?

Comment: ` const varsForm = {
    NewYork: document.getElementById("location1").checked,
    textNewYork: document.getElementById("location1").checked ? 'YES': 'NO',
  };`

Here it will check if its true then it will initial yes else no to textNewYork property.

Comment: Also if my answer help or solved your issue please mark it as answer useful thank you.